# In PowerBI (DAX) how to total sum in the first and last year for only names that are present in all years

Tags: count, sum, powerbi, dax, find-occurrences

Need help with Power BI DAX to be find total amount in the first year for only those names that are present in all the years.

Here is a sample table:

**Name  Year    Amount**

**A**   2015    100

B   2015    50

**C**   2015    150

**A**   2016    200

B   2016    150

**C**   2016    150

**A**   2017    300

**C**   2017    300

D   2017    250

**A**   2018    300

**C**   2018    300

D   2018    300

E   2018    500

In the above table A and C are present in all the years, and hence I want total amount for both A and C in the starting year

Result:

**2015**

250

How do I achieve this? The key is only for those names that are present consistently in the year range.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Regards,
Naresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following. It loops over any Name value in the current context and then it counts the number of years for that Name and if it matches the total number of years it sums up the amount for that Name.

```
SUMX(
 VALUES(Tbl[Name]),
 IF(
   CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Tbl[Year]), ALLEXCEPT(Tbl, Tbl[Name]))
   = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Tbl[Year]), ALL(Tbl)),
   CALCULATE(SUM(Tbl[Amount]))
  )
 )

//tweaking your attempt by including ALLSELECTED() and not including Year in ALLEXCEPT
VAR FromYear = CALCULATE(MIN('Tbl'[Year]),ALLSELECTED())
VAR ToYear = CALCULATE(MAX('Tbl'[Year]), ALLSELECTED())
VAR CountYears = ToYear - FromYear + 1 
RETURN 
SUMX (
 VALUES ( 'Tbl'[Name] ), 
 IF ( 
  CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Tbl'[Year] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Tbl', 'Tbl'[Name], 'Tbl'[Category] )) = CountYears, 
  CALCULATE(SUM('Tbl'[Amount]) , 'Tbl'[Year]=FromYear)
 )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Greg for your response!

There are some filters like year range  (user can specify the start year and end year) and other filters. So, I am not sure if All(Tbl) can be used. Also, the requirement is to get the sum of amount in  the starting year and ending year separately.

Comment: Updated using yours. please review and correct. Thank you!

@@Initial amount for same names = 
VAR FromYear =  MIN('Tbl'[Year])
VAR ToYear = MAX('Tbl'[Year])
VAR CountYears = ToYear - FromYear + 1
RETURN
SUMX (VALUES ( 'Tbl'[Name] ),
    IF ( CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Tbl'[Year] ),
            ALLEXCEPT (
                    'Tbl',
                    'Tbl'[Name], 'Tbl'[Year],
                    'Tbl'[Category]
                    ))
            = CountYears,
            CALCULATE(SUM('Tbl'[Amount])
                    , 'Tbl'[Year]=FromYear)))

Comment: @Naresh thanks for the clarifications. I tweaked your code. See revision above

Comment: @Naresh that’s not really the way this works. If we take threads offline then the community can’t benefit from answers posted online. Can you share what slicers/filters you have and what results you are getting and what you expect?

Comment: I agree Greg! I thought that by discussing directly and later posting an update. But sure, will share details and we can continue the discussion here. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: I created a sample data to test the solution, and your solution works like a charm!!! Thanks Greg!

btw, please help me understand why VALUES(Tbl[Name]) is used in SUMX?Thanks!

Comment: @Naresh that’s great news. If my answer helped then please mark the green checkmark so the community knows the solution